# Cut the text length as the screen gets smaller

Tags: html, css

I want the text length to shrink when the screen gets smaller

```html
<div class="dress-card hvr-bob">
  <div class="dress-card-head">
    <img class="dress-card-img-top" src="img/rdr2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="dress-card-body">
    <h2 class="dress-card-title">Red Dead Redemption 2</h2>
    <p class="dress-card-para">Social Club Key</p>
    <p class="dress-card-para"><span class="dress-card-price">200TL &ensp;</span>
      <!--<span class="dress-card-crossed">300TL</span><span class="dress-card-off">&ensp;İndirim!</span>--></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 card-button">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
          <div class="card-button-inner bag-button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Satın Al</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 card-button">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="">
          <div class="card-button-inner wish-button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i> Sepete Ekle</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

help

Comment: what do you mean by shrink? to be small in small screens or to show some of the text only instead of full text?

Comment: This question is too generic. Please provide a demo and/or be more specific about the output you want to achieve.

Comment: As the screen gets smaller, the title section ends with three dots.

Comment: Please google "ellipsis css" - There are plenty of demos for this because it's quite common

Answer (score 0):

Add `font-size:8vw;` to your CSS. You can add it to `p` or specific for a class or id.
You can change the 8 to any number you want.
I hope thats what you searching :)